# Redirected: Is there a way to "grab" urls I'm being redirected through?

Tags: logging, redirection, url

Let's say I'm visiting yourwebsite.com which redirects to somethingelse.com which redirects to somethingdifferent.com before taking me to finalpage.com. All of this happens in an instant, so quickly that I'm unable to make out what urls are.

Is there a way I can figure out what the urls I'm being redirected through are, before making it to the end page... as a user? Sorry for the vague description of the question. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Redirect Check](http://www.internetofficer.com/seo-tool/redirect-check/) worth trying to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Firefox browser, try installing the Live HTTP Headers add-on.  It can be configured to capture redirects.  Other browsers may have similar tools, but I am not aware of them.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has an option called "Warn me when websites try to redirect or reload the page".

You can enable it in Options (Preferences in Linux) -> Advanced.

Once enabled, Firefox will warn you if any page is attempting a redirect.